# Trouble adding http://mainserver/ to all (href|action|src)=, take me into a trouble!

Tags: php, html, regex

I have this URLs...

```
$output = "href=\"/one/two/three\"
href=\"one/two/three\"
src=\"windows.jpg\"
action=\"http://www.google.com/docs\"";
```

When I apply the regular expression:

```
$base_url_page = "http://mainserver/";
$output = preg_replace( "/(href|src|action)(\s*)=(\s*)(\"|\')(\/+|\/*)(.*)(\"|\')/ismU", "$1=\"" . $base_url_page . "$6\"", $output );
```

I get this:

```
$output = "href=\"http://mainserver/one/two/three\"
href=\"http://mainserver/one/two/three\"
src=\"http://mainserver/windows.jpg\"
action=\"http://mainserver/http://www.google.com/docs\"";
```

How you can modify the regular expression to prevent this: http://mainserver/http://www.google.com/ ???????

Comment: Some advice on HTML parsing with regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Would it suffice to just change the base URI with the [`BASE` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$output = preg_replace( "/(href|src|action)\s*=\s*["'](?!http)\/*([^"']*)["']/ismU", "$1=\"" . $base_url_page . "$2\"", $output );
```

I have simplified your regex and added a lookahead that makes sure the string you're matching doesn't start with `http`. As it is now, this regex allows neither single nor double quotes inside the URL.

Comment: This won’t allow attribute values containing a plain `'` like `href="http://example.com/foo'bar"` (and this *is* a valid URI!).

Comment: I know, that's why I wrote so in my answer. If this is a problem for the OP, the regex can be changed.

Comment: this solution is great, thanks... the only when the href="/url" ... we will get in the result: href=http://mainserver//url ---> // ?? (In my Regex I resolved this using: (\/+|\/*) ) ....

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - a URL like `href="/url/foo"` will be transformed into `http://mainserver/url/foo` in my tests. Is this wrong? Could you perhaps edit your question with an example that's currently not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = preg_replace( "/(href|src|action)\s*=\s*[\"'](?!http)(\/+|\/*)([^\"']*)[\"']/ismU", "$1=\"" . $base_url_page . "$3\"", $output );
```